# Django - Import Error: No module named *.urls

Tags: python, django

I'm working through the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) and adapting it slightly for my own needs using Django version 1.6.1, Python 2.7.6.

I'm at the point where it has me mapping URLs but I keep getting "No module named customers.urls" errors when there is very clearly a module with an aptly named file within, so I'm really at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

My initial thought was that I needed to import something customers-related in the root/urls.py but every combination of import resulted in roughly the same error, and the tutorial did not say to do this.

ROOT_URLCONF = 'taco.urls' (taco is the name of the project)

I'm running this using manage.py/runserver so there's no special web server trickery going on that I'm aware of. I've restarted it several times.

The apps are all properly registered, as the traceback can attest.

Any pointers as to something I'm overlooking would be appreciated!

root/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^customers/', include('customers.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

customers/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url;

from customers import views;

urlpatterns = ('', 
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
);
```

customers/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse;

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello");
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.3.208:8000/customers/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'taco.customers',
 'taco.inventory',
 'taco.lookups',
 'taco.orders')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  99.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/var/project/taco/taco/urls.py" in <module>
  7.     url(r'^customers/', include('customers.urls')),
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /customers/
Exception Value: No module named customers.urls
```

Comment: Add `'customers'` to the `Installed Applications`

Comment: It's already added as "taco.customers."

Comment: Two things 1. I think you need to add `taco` in the installed apps. 2. You probably need to do `include('taco.customers.urls')` in the main `urls.py`

Comment: Please don't end lines with semicolons in Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Sorry, some habits die hard :\

Comment: @shaktimaan - "Taco" isn't an app, it's the entire project. Either way specifying 'taco.customers.urls' is a logical solution but doesn't change anything.

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` in the package `customers` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your customers/urls.py:

Change this:

```
urlpatterns = ('', 
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
);
```

For this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
);
```

Also, make sure you have your `__init__.py` file in package `customers`. And that `INSTALLED_APPS` is correctly filled with you app name.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    'customers',
    'inventory',
    'lookups',
    'orders',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If taco is the name of the project check that apps are being referenced correctly so in your installed apps you may need the following:

```
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'customers',
 'inventory',
 'lookups',
 'orders')
```

Comment: That was one of my initial thoughts, but it doesn't change anything whether I add the full path or not.

Comment: Ok yes you did state that taco was the name of the project. In which case you don't need to add taco.appname to the installed apps you can just use the app name not prepended with taco.